# How to find the number of cubes in a cube pattern where cube at center has 4 cubes along the arms

Tags: algorithm

I have been struggling with the below hackerEarth issue since morning and wouldn't know what is wrong.
Could you point to the mistake in the code?

In a cubical pattern, lowermost and uppermost layers contain 1 cube. The next inner levels contain 5 cubes each such that there is a cube in the center and 4 cubes covering the central one along the arms. Ina similar way, the inner levels contain 13 cubes and so on. The number of cubes in successive layers irst increase upto ((n+1)/2)th level and then start decreasing, in the same manner, i.e. the shape is symmetric.

For a given integer N (which is an odd number) find the cubes.
[image]

Ex: Let N =7 then the sequence of cube layers is as follows: 1, 5, 13, 25, 13, 5, 1. So for N = 7, the answer is 1 + 5 + 13 + 5 + 1 = 63.

The following code I have written doesn't seem to work for all test cases and apparently takes more time than expected.

```
    static ulong FindCubes(long N)
    {
       if (N == 1)
            return 1;
        if (N == 2)
            return 5;

        ulong factor = 4, sum = 1, lastNum =1;

        for (int i = 1; i < (N / 2 + 1); i++)
        {                
            lastNum += factor;
            sum += lastNum;                
            factor += 4;
        }
        return sum * 2 - lastNum; ;
    }
```

Comment: Try deriving a mathematical formula using `Arithmetic Progressions` so that you don't have to iterate from 1 to N.

Comment: Or cheat and refer to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: The arithmetic progression is :  2 * n * (n + 1) + 1; I still have to loop for N/2 + 1 times right, and find the sum? I know there is a better way, but it is not apparent to me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do so, indeed as mentioned in the comments the most efficient way (in my opinion) is to perform an `Arithmetic Progressions` and find a formula for each number in the series - according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_square_number) it is:

> n^2 + (n-1)^2

But don't stop there! Now you can find using the same method the general element in the series:

> sum n^2 + (n-1)^2, n=1 to k

Which according to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5E2%2B%28n-1%29%5E2%2C+n%3D1+to+k) is

> 1/3 * (k + 2 * k^3)

So now you can write a simple python code:

```py
n = 7
# Calculate number of layers to sum
layers = (n - 1) / 2
# Sum the layers using the new formula
sum_of_layers = 1/3 * (layers + 2 * layers ** 3)
# Adding the middle item (for N=7 it would be 25)
middle_index = layers + 1
# Using the formula from the Arithmetic Progressions
middle_item = middle_index ** 2 + (middle_index-1) ** 2
# Printing the result
print(int(sum_of_layers * 2 + middle_item))
```

Resulting in:

> 63